# Download file from MTP connected device with Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, file-transfer, mtp, pymtp

I'm trying to download a file from an MTP connected device.

```py
import pymtp

device = pymtp.MTP()

device.connect()

print(device.get_filelisting())

for file in device.get_filelisting():
    if file.item_id == 2000018:
        device.get_file_to_file(file.item_id, "/home/enws/Desktop/")

device.disconnect()
```

And I get this in the terminal which isn't very helpful to me in finding my error.

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
[b'gara.docx' (2000017)]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Has anyone used pymtp on linux with python version `3.6.5` before?

Can anyone help me understand this error?

Or are there alternatives for this? I just want to be able to read files on a connected USB device and download them to local.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04 if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [mtpy](https://github.com/ldo/mtpy) instead, which worked without problems. Although, it doesn't have everything implemented.

Comment: It seems that this library no longer exists (perhaps because there is a name clash with a different mtpy library which is for metallurgy)